# onMouseLeave triggers when entering Element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to simulate a hover event in React. 
So I am using `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave`
that triggers the statechange.

Unfortunately when I first enter the Element with the mouse both methods are triggered...

When I leave the Element only onMouseLeave`is triggered.
Does anyone knows why the method`onMouseLeave` is triggered on entering the element.

**Here is my Code:**

```js
   handleOver(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('enter');
        if(this.state.open === false){
            this.setState({
                open: true,
                anchorEl: event.currentTarget,
            });
        }
    }
    
    handleLeave(event){
         event.preventDefault();
         console.log('leave');
         if(this.state.open === true){
             this.setState({open: false})
         }
    }
```

```html
                    <img
                        onMouseEnter={this.handleOver}
                        onMouseLeave={this.handleLeave}
                        src={InfoIcon}
                    />
                    
                    <Popover
                        open={this.state.open}
                        anchorEl={this.state.anchorEl}
                        anchorOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}
                        targetOrigin={{horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'top'}}
                        onRequestClose={this.handleLeave}
                        muiTheme={darkBaseTheme}
                    />
```

Comment: Which version of react are you using. This may be related to this bug : [https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10906](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10906)

Comment: I am using version 15.6.1

Answer (score 16):

Technically, this is not a bug, since the `onMouseEnter` event is triggered correctly, which causes the `Popover` component to render with a backdrop over the page, which triggers the `onMouseLeave` event.

This "issue" is discussed at [[Popover] event handlers issue (mouseEnter and mouseLeave) #7680](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/7680).

Credit goes to [konradwww](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811604/konradwww), for listing the following explanation, that leads to the behavior any sane person would expect:

```
<Popover
style={{ pointerEvents: 'none'}}
...
```

Comment: Heads up to others that this can be the issue even when you aren't using popovers! I had an absolute positioned element that should have been entirely outside of the hoverable area, but it still needed pointerEvents none.